# C# Request.Browser.Type list

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, browser

I'm trying to identify the browser my users are using as `display:none` is used frequently in a site I'm maintaining so we need to make sure users are using browsers that support this.

`Request.Browser.Type` returns a string identifying the browser being used but there doesn't appear to be overly reliable (Edge returns as Chrome for example) nor can I find a list of what the string *should* be for each browser.

Any better solutions to feature checking CSS property support appreciated!

Comment: `so we need to make sure users are using browsers that support this.` Which browser **doesn't** support `display: none`?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365117/reliable-device-browser-os-detection may be of assistance.

Comment: @mjwills Not many, but had a customer use an old iPad and it caused all sorts of problems
https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Anone

Comment: its more that we don't support them, but need to make sure they can't access certain areas

Comment: you really think I'm using `display:none` to restrict access? The areas we don't want them using use `display:none` for conditional elements of the UI, that fails if not supported by the browser. I want to stop them accessing those areas in the back end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my controller(s) to identify the correct browser:

```
string browser = Request.Browser.Browser;
//As you noted, Request.Browser.Browser for Edge returns Chrome
//But comparing that with the Request.UserAgent and checking if UserAgent contains Edge, works for me
if (browser != "Edge" && Request.UserAgent.Contains("Edge"))
    browser = "Edge";
```

Here are a couple of links which show user agent strings for some of the most used browsers:

Shows Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari, Firefox
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Shows Edge:
(http://www.webapps-online.com/online-tools/user-agent-strings/dv/browser646202/edge-browser)

Comment: That works for Edge, but how am I meant to know what Request.Browser.Type returns for Safari for iOS? or UC for Android? or even Opera? I know I can search the UserAgent, but it seems silly that there isn't a list for Request.Browser.Type

Comment: This list has them all: https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/
but it just surprises me this is so poorly documented

Comment: @Dystar So, for me, I am only developing internal websites for the company I work for, so they are using browsers on a PC or MAC. I currently haven't had to account for mobile, but the `Request.Browser.Browser` has worked well for the popular browsers other than Edge, which is why I did what I did in the code above. It would probably be best if I came up with a solution which looks at the UserAgent string, but I currently don't have a solution like that. I can remove my answer if you don't think it is beneficial.

Comment: It's totally a valid answer :) Not your fault the possible results of `Request.Browser.Type` or `Request.Browser.Browser` aren't documented :)

Comment: @Dystar Thanks. I'll leave it up then. I hope this was of some help.